# How to make spaghetti stack with C?

Tags: c, callstack, coroutine

I'm trying to make coroutine and continuation with C. I realized I need some kind of spaghetti stack. Is it possible to execute a function within a new call-stack? Of course within  single thread. How can I make a new, separated call-stack, and execute some code on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still not sure about continuations, but at least for coroutine, there's no good way to do this within C. Because this is out of C abstraction. `setjmp/longjmp` has limitation of scope may disrupts C++/Objective-C exception system, `makecontext/swapcontext` has been deprecated. Though some systems still support the functions, but at least Apple OS does not support it anymore.

The only acceptable solution to me was [`libtask` library](http://swtch.com/libtask/). Which uses architecture specific assembly codes to save and restore register state, and it also manages the call stacks. I think it is using monolithic stack and still have size limit, but anyway, it's almost the only solution I could find which reliably working.

I think [Clang's Segmented Stack](http://llvm.org/docs/SegmentedStacks.html) (or GCC's Split  Stack) feature will enable very generic coroutine support on C level. And I hope to write coroutine code on LLVM freely later.

Answer (score 5):

check out makecontext/swapcontext.

If those aren't available, then you could use setjmp/longjmp, but those are a little more complex.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Windows, you can look into the [Fibers API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682661%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).  Evil Otto's answer is more portable/POSIX compliant, however.